# Is $\mathbb{N}$ a subset of countably infinite unions of $A_{n}$ defined below?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $\left\{A_{n}\right\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of sets such that:

$$\begin{align}
A_{0} &= \left\{\left\{0\right\}\right\},\\
A_{1} &= \left\{\left\{0\right\}, \left\{0, 1\right\}\right\},\\
A_{2} &= \left\{\left\{0\right\}, \left\{0, 1\right\}, \left\{0,1,2\right\}\right\},\\
A_n &= \{\{0\}, \{0,1\},\dots, \{0,1,2,\dots, n\}\}\\
&\vdots
\end{align}
$$

Is $\mathbb{N} \in \bigcup\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_{n}$ ?

Indeed, I assumed this counterexample to debate with my friend, who argued that, for countably infinite unions $\bigcup\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_{n}$, if $a\in\bigcup\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_{n}$, then there exists $n_{0} \in \mathbb{N}$, such that $a \in A_{n_{0}}$, just like the case for finite unions.

However, I don't agree with it, since I think I can prove that $\mathbb{N} = \bigcup\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left\{0,1,...,n\right\}$. For any $k \in \mathbb{N}$, $k \in \left\{0,1,...,k\right\} \subset \bigcup\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left\{0,1,...,n\right\}$, then $\mathbb{N} \subset \bigcup\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left\{0,1,...,n\right\}$. For the other side of proof, firstly, each component of $\bigcup\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left\{0,1,...,n\right\}$ only contains natural numbers, then $\bigcup\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left\{0,1,...,n\right\}$ only contains natural numbers, hence $\bigcup\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left\{0,1,...,n\right\} \subset \mathbb{N}$.

My questioning is that, if I can use countably infinite unions of "induction" sets to define $\mathbb{N}$, why couldn't I apply the same way to show the above relationship? However, if my assumption is correct, then we cannot find such a $n_{0} \in \mathbb{N}$, such that $\mathbb{N} \in A_{n_{0}}$, because $A_{n_{0}}$ is always finite but $\mathbb{N}$ is infinite.

Comment: Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)'s a quick guide.

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote. Even if the question is closed, you can still edit it, and we will vote to reopen it.

Comment: If $\mathbb{N}$ is an element of the union, there must be some $n$ such that $\mathbb{N} \in A_n$.

Comment: I observe that $\cup_n A_n$ is a collection of sets, while $\cup_n \{0, 1, 2, ..., n\}$ is a collection of integers.  They are not the same thing. That is why the former is a collection of sets that does not include the set $\mathbb{N}$, while the latter is a set of numbers that contains $\mathbb{N}$ as a subset. So indeed $\mathbb{N} \subseteq \cup_n \{0, 1, 2, ..., n\}$ and $\mathbb{N} \notin \cup_n A_n$.

Comment: Thanks @Michael for your answer. Is "If $\mathbb{N}$ is an element of the union, then must be some n such that $\mathbb{N} \in A_{n}$" the definition?

Comment: Yes, the definition of a union of sets is the set of all objects that are elements of least one of the sets. Note that there is a difference between $\subseteq$ and $\in$. For example, the empty set is a subset of every set, but it is not an element of every set.